# Completeness of the codomain of a surjective continuous map implies completeness of the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:(X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ be continuous and surjective map between metric spaces such that
$$d_X(x_1,x_2) \leq d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2)).$$
Prove or disprove:

1. If $X$ is complete then $Y$ is complete.
2. If $Y$ is complete then $X$ is complete.

The first is easy since, using the inequality, one can construct a Cauchy sequence in $X$ as the preimage of a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ and then use completeness of $X$ and continuity of $f$. The second I think is false, but I am not able to think of a counter example. I know that the image of a Cauchy sequence is not necessarily Cauchy under only continuous maps (need uniform continuity). Any ideas how to solve 2. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map (both sets with the Euclidean metric)
$$ f:(0;1] \rightarrow [1;\infty), x\mapsto 1/x.$$
This map is continuous and bijective. Furthermore,
$$ d_Y(f(x),f(y))=\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert = \vert 1/x -1/y\vert = \frac{\vert x-y\vert}{\vert xy\vert} \geq \vert x-y\vert =d_X(x,y).$$
However, $X=(0;1]$ is incomplete and $Y=[1;\infty)$ is complete.

Note that $f$ is actually a homeomorphism. This also tells you that completeness is not preserved under homeomorphism.